# Unity WebGL video file format

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Despite looking at the Unity manual at the video codec requirements, there isn’t an option for WebGL.

I’ve created a scene, and I have added video player which renders the video in the Unity game window; however, when I come to run the game in WebGL the video is playing yet there is no audio. On the GameObject holding the video player, I have attached another GameObject with an audio source but still does not seem to play the video. Have I missed something from my code to enable audio or set the video’s audio to the audio source? I have dragged and dropped the audio source GameObject on to the video player audio source option already.

```
    public GameObject videoPlayerHolder;

    void Awake()
    {
        videoPlayer = this.gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        videoPlayer.Play();
        videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;
        videoPlayer.url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Intromemoji-1MP4.mp4");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed (almost) to answer this question, after a decent length of time with zero answers.

It turns out that any H.264 encoder will create playable the video so long as it is a.Webm file - no other file formats would seem to work for me.

Note: This worked fine for most browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera and Internet Explorer); however, Safari I could not get any video to play with or without sound. I feel this is due to CORS or I read something else to do with iFrames not allowing automatic audio in Safari to prevent noisy popups. Still, I've not found a comprehensive solution to this issue.